# Microsoft Bot framework "ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - no security token sent"

Tags: node.js, facebook, botframework, messenger

I am using Node.js and my bot framework version is 3.3.3. I have already configured "Skype" channel and its working fine. However in case of "Facebook Messenger" I am getting error "No security token sent". I am using ngrok . Here is my configuration of chatBot

```js
var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.CORS());
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 4000, function() {
  console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});
// Create chat bot
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: _config.ms.appId,
  appPassword: _config.ms.password
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

server.post('/', connector.listen());

server.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (req.query.hub.verify_token === _config.ms.messengerSecret) {
    res.write(req.query.hub.challenge);
    res.end();
  } else {
    res.send('Error, wrong validation token');
  }
});
```

I have attached screenshots of configuration of webhooks(facebook app) and messaging end point(botframwork).[webhook configuration(app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHfX1.png)[image: Messaging end point]

Comment: In fact I have tried with updating messaging end point https://c5dcbaa5.ngrok.io/api/messages but it also didn't work for me. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any errors in our Facebook logs for the bot handle vChat.  Lots of reconfiguration ( I assume changing the endpoint for ngrok ) but it doesn't seem like there are any requests making it to us for Facebook channel, or errors showing up in the dev portal.

Are you seeing any fiddler trace of messages leaving your machine?

Comment: Thanks for your response! whenever I sent message to vChat I got this error on my local machine "Error : ChatConnector: receive - no security token sent." . However whenever I test [here](https://dev.botframework.com/bots?id=vChat), it says accepted.

Comment: In my facebook app I am getting alert like this "Your Webhooks subscription for callback URL https://c5dcbaa5.ngrok.io/ has not been accepting updates for the past 8 hours. This subscription has been disabled. To reactivate, just make a POST request with the same parameters or visit the Webhooks tab in the app dashboard. Learn more about Webhooks."

Comment: I have opened an issue   https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1505 . Please have a look.
Thanks!!